# phpQuery: Replace all occurrences of text with another

Tags: php, phpquery

I am trying to parse a website homepage to convert it into xml file to be used as an api in my app.

So far I have successfully done so. However, the parsed text contains the `&` (ampersand) character which causes the XML parser to fail.

I am looking for a solution that doesn't use the `CDATA` or doesn't output `CDATA` in the XML file.

I want to replace `&` with `and` at every occurrence. What phpQuery method should I use?

This causes error in browser because the text() method returns a text with

`&` character in it.

```
require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

 $all=phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('BPUT.htm', $charset = 'utf-8');

 $links = $all['a.myblue'];


echo '<notice>';

foreach ($links as $link) {

    echo '<text>';
    echo pq($link)->text();
    echo '</text>';


    echo '<url>';
    echo pq($link)->attr('href');
    echo '</url>';
}

echo '</notice>';

 ?>
```

I do not want to use CDATA, as the CDATA tag is visible in the generated XML :

```
 <?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

 $all=phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('BPUT.htm', $charset = 'utf-8');

 $links = $all['a.myblue'];


echo '<notice>';

foreach ($links as $link) {

    echo '<text>';
    echo "<![CDATA[";
    echo pq($link)->text();
    echo "]]>";
    echo '</text>';


    echo '<url>';
    echo pq($link)->attr('href');
    echo '</url>';
}

echo '</notice>';

 ?>
```

bumping for answers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You're likely to get a better response here if you can show what you've tried so far, explain exactly why you're stuck, and include a concise example that others can use to test suggestions. Otherwise, it can feel a bit like we are just being asked to do all the hard work for you.

Comment: I understand. I parsed a website to get all links & converted it into xml using phpQuery.
But the text has one ampersand character at one place which causes the xml page to fail when opened in a browser.
So I want to manipulate the parsed HTML to replace the amp character, so that it does not cause error when converted into XML

Comment: Can you edit the question to show some of the code you have so far, and a sample of the HTML causing the problem?

Comment: I have provided the code. Pls have a look at it.

Comment: Does the return of text() have any xml in it, or is it just text which also happens to have an apersand (&) in it?

Comment: Its plain text. As you can see in the code, I have inserted xml tags myself.